# what terminates a while loop when its expression is a conditional expression

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

the title says it all

in a loop likes this written in C

```
while(first_statement ? second_statement : third_statement)
```

how can a loop like this be terminated?

Comment: Are those actual difference calculations, because if not, kindly remove the math and make the *expressions* clearer.

Comment: It will only terminate if `statement` returns `2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A loop using `while(statement1 ? statement2 : statement3)` will be terminated if at a time when the condition is tested, either of the following apply:

- `statement1` evaluates to non-zero and `statement2` evaluates to zero
- `statement1` evaluates to zero and `statement3` evaluates to zero

(It can of course also be terminated by things such as a `break` statement or a `return` from the function that contains it.)

Comment: I am assuming here that the `statement-1` in the question as currently stated is not literally intended to refer to subtraction of value `1` from a variable called `statement`, similiarly `statement-2` and `statement-3`.

Answer (score 0):

Taking they are just statements and not mathematical expressions,I think the while loop runs unless the expression inside it evaluates to 0.
So if n=5,
while(n--? 1:0)
This condition runs for 5 times.